# Run an exe with options in Golang

Tags: go, exe

I have an .exe installer, let's say installer.exe
On command line, I can run the following command:

```
installer /quiet OPT=XY
```

It runs successfully and uses those options.

Now, I want to run the same thing using GoLang code

To just run the installer, the following works:

```
cmd := exec.Command("CryptovisorClient")
```

However, I want to run the entire command with the options -  `installer /quiet OPT=XY`

How do I achieve this in the Go code?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [exec.Command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command)'s docs. It shows that the args can be passed in as a variadic. Therefore you should be able to do:

```
cmd := exec.Command("installer", "/quiet", "OPT=XY")
```

Now, I don't do much windows (and it looks like those are windows style flags), but I believe that will work.